# Calling anonymous function in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, annotations

I have a question on pulling anonymous functions to an HTML.
This is my HTML line of code:

```
onclick="functionToPull('map')"
```

functionToPull would be the name of the function if it was not anonymous.
How do I pull an anonymous javascript function?

Example:

```
(function (){

})();
```

Comment: Just put `onclick="INSERT_ANON_FUNCTION_HERE"`

Comment: By wrapping the function in an enclosure you are preventing that function from existing at all in global scope, which is what the HTML can access. The only way I can think of for making this work is setting onclick for that element inside the javascript...

Comment: Try setting up the onClick event in js

Comment: @ Lucio Where exactly? In the HTML code or the JS? If in JS, how would I call it to the HTML.

Comment: @sergey, I gave you the answer below...

Answer (score 24):

Putting your event handler in the click event is considered a bad practice, except for frameworks like Angular. The recommended approach would be to create an event handler like so,

```
document.getElementById("myElement").addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("Hello World!"); });
```

But if you really want to do it that way, here's what you wanted:

```
<body>
    <button onclick='(function(){ console.log("Hello World"); })();'></button>
  </body>
```

You can see it in action in this plunker.[anonymous function plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xLNKrlZB4tOIXlvXboay?p=preview)

Comment: I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: @sergey This is most likely because there is no element in your document matching the specified ID.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Razor, you can do something like this:

```
public bool Collapsed { get; set; } = false;

<div>
    @if (Collapsed == false)
    {
        <MatFAB Icon="@MatIconNames.Keyboard_arrow_up" OnClick="@(async () => Collapsed = true)" Style="margin:auto; display:flex;" ></MatFAB>
    }
    else
    {
        <MatFAB Icon="@MatIconNames.Keyboard_arrow_down" OnClick="@(async () => Collapsed = false)" Style="margin:auto; display:flex;"></MatFAB>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#syntax)

`<button onclick="(()=>{})()"></button>`

#### Example

```html
<button onclick="(()=>{
  console.log('do something1')
  console.log('do something2')
})()">example1</button>

<button onclick="(()=>{
  window.game.name +='!'
  console.log(window.game.name)
}
  )()
">example2
</button>


<script type="module">
  class Game {
    constructor(name) {
      this.name = name
    }
  }
  const game = new Game("breakout")
  window.game = game // set dummy attribute for window
</script>
```