# Invoking anonymous function in Angular 2+ templates

Tags: javascript, angular

I'd like to define small functions inside my html template so as to not fill up my `component.ts` file with a lot of small dumb functions. Is there any way I could achieve something like the following (which doesn't work)?

```
<button (click)="(()=>{console.log('Invoked from inline')})()">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14129

Comment: You just need to do <button onclick="here_your_function">Click me!</button>. Source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42799142/calling-anonymous-function-in-html?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<button onclick="console.log('Invoked from inline')">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Im pretty sure any linter will complain about `console` not being defined in the scope.

Comment: I already knew how to log stuff on the console - I want the function to be able to do whatever a component method can do